# Unix cron job for shell scripts

Tags: unix, cron

I would like to have a cron job which executes 3 shell scripts consecutively i.e., execution of next shell script depending on the completion of previous scripts.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example showing a cron which executes 3 scripts at 9am Mon-Fri.

```
00 09 * * 1-5 script1.sh && script2.sh && script3.sh 2>&1 >> /var/tmp/cron.log
```

If any one of the scripts fails, the next script in the sequence will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Write one script which calls these three scripts and pit it into cron.

Comment: This has the added advantage that you can run the three shell scripts consecutively from the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on yi_H's answer: You can combine them in one shell script in different ways, depending on what you want.

```
job1.sh
job2.sh
job3.sh
```

will run all three consecutively, regardless of the result.

```
job1.sh && job2.sh && job3.sh
```

will run all three, but it will stop if one of them fails (that is, if job1 returns an error, job2 and job3 will not run).

Comment: The `-e` shell option is useful here too (`#!/bin/sh -e`).